# Scanning a CSV file with scanf() in a loop stops after the first line and beginning of second

Tags: c, csv, struct, binary-search-tree

I need to read in a huge CSV file and store it in a struct, to be inserted into a binary search tree (but that's another story) however I can only get the first four columns to be read in (one line has four columns)- any ideas?

Intended output:

```
Michael,21,M,12345
Susan,34,F,13342
Robin,12,F,45423
Teddy,43,M,56231
Ed,21,M,34354
Ramirez,21,F,79563
Toby,32,M,34277
Guy,23,M,90765
Desiree,21,F,67453
Molly,24,F,45434
Alison,23,F,62356
Tara,26,F,45223
Sally,21,F,34545
Mike,20,M,67676
Roger,19,M,83737
David,21,M,78554
Davis,23,M,66554
Sheng,22,M,31211
Wesley,31,M,21436
```

etc. but I am getting

```
Michael,21,M,12345
Susan
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 128

typedef struct{
    char name[MAXLEN];
    char age[MAXLEN];
    char sex[MAXLEN];
    char courseID[MAXLEN];
}input_t;

typedef struct{
    input_t input;
    struct bst *left;
    struct bst *right;
} bst;

void parse_csv(bst *node);
void print_csv(bst node);

void parse_csv(bst *node){
    while (scanf(" %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", node->input.name, node->input.age, node->input.sex, node->input.courseID) == 4) {
        break;
    }
}

void print_csv(bst node){
  printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n",node.input.name, node.input.age, node.input.sex, node.input.courseID);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bst node;
    parse_csv(&node);
    print_csv(node);
    return 0;
}
```

[how the csv looks like, we will be given bigger test files to test on, though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtOAa.png)

Comment: This is a perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially some [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your `parse_csv` function would be very useful.

Comment: You should probably learn a little more about [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and how to use the `"%["` format.

Comment: Please show the first few lines of the CSV file in the question, unless the 'intended output' is exactly representative of the input.  Note that a picture of a spreadsheet looks nothing like the input data!  Also, is the trailing comma after "Robin" in the intended output really intended, and if so, why?

Comment: I am tolerably certain you'd do best reading a line at a time (with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) and then scanning it with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Why did you put a blank line betwenn _every_ line. It doesn't makle your code more readable.

Comment: The "," at the end of your sample data line 3 breaks the pattern. Is it a typo or a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've just edited to include the full intended output.

Comment: In order to find a solution (I do not want to guess in my answer), what happens if you delete the `break` and replace `,]\n` -> `,\n]` ? Does it show only the last line?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please use blank lines more sparingly in your code; it actually makes it harder to read if everything is double-spaced. Your problem is that (1) the last field on a line should be terminated by white space, not a comma, so your last conversion should be `%s` (probably) rather than `%[^,]`. As written, and as diagnosed by Yunnosch, you get the number, the newline, and Susan in the last field, and then (if you called the `scanf()` again, but you don't because of `break`), the next conversion would fail because there's a comma next and commas aren't allowed by the format.

Comment: @Yunnosch ok, that got rid of the "Susan" but still printing Michael,21,M,12345 only.

Comment: Did you delete the `break`?

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry, I just saw your suggestion. Yes I just deleted the break, and now it is printing the last line of the csv.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  when the parameters are not going to be used, then use the signature `int main( void )`.  Then the compiler will not be outputting the warnings about unused parameters

Comment: OT: should always include a 'tag' name on a struct definition so it will be easy to display in a debugger.

Comment: the posted code has the logic error of always placing the data in the SAME node when the definition of the `bst` struct indicates that there should be a doubly linked list of those nodes

Answer (score 4):

This could read repeatedly (assuming the formatting is perfect and see below);
though always into the same node.

```
while (scanf(" %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", 
       node->input.name,  
       node->input.age, 
       node->input.sex, 
       node->input.courseID) == 4) {
```

This spoils the fun, by stopping unconditionally after the first time.

```
    break;
}
```

The "Susan", which seems to imply the start of reading a second row, is actually read as part of the first row, because of unsuitable format specifier, which allows reading anything non-",", including the newline and Susan.

In a comment you confirm that changing `,]\n` -> `,\n]` fixes the line parsing and gets you a correctly scanned first line.

If you also delete the `break`, scanning your CSV should work.
"Work" as in "read all the CSV, ignoring most of it and storing only the last line". In order to show more than one line you need of course

- a data structure which can store more than one line (probably your BST)
- fill that BST where currently your `break` is
- change `print_csv()` to show the whole tree in some way

or

- call `print_csv()` in a way to show the whole tree

Also see additional input by Jonathan Leffler in the comments on this answer.
They refer to what you describe as "another story".

As a side note (also mentioned by Jonathan Leffler):
This use case of a perfectly formatted and intended (probably generated) CSV can be handled by `scanf()` as one of the few exceptions. For anything with the slightest doubt on correct formatting, most prominently user input, the scanf() family is inappropriate, reading whole lines and doing error-tolerant parsing explicitly is the way to go there.
However, even in case of intended input being perfectly formatted, consider malicious input and protect yourself by restricting the length of scanned fields, in order to avoid writing beyond your arrays, e.g. beyond `char name[MAXLEN]` or 
`char courseID[MAXLEN]` depending on how your compiler arranges structs.

Comment: This is basically correct.  Of course, there are also some memory allocation issues that will need to be resolved if the loop is fixed so that it loops.  Unless something is done in the body of the `while` loop you accurately dissect, the same node will be overwritten on each iteration with new data, so in the end only the last line will be stored in the one node.  Creating a BST with the data will require some extra memory management — presumably dynamic memory allocation.  Given that the initial node is not dynamically allocated, care will be required when the memory freeing code is written.